# How to store PHAsset into Core Data

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, photo

I am selecting images from Photos and iCloud. I want to store PHAsset into core data. How can we store PHAsset into core data?.

Before that I was storing local image URL, but some local urls are private.So I was not able to fetch image.

Comment: CoreData has `Transformable` type, did you try it?

Comment: @QuocNguyen when I use Transformable type, It gets cresh with log "Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[PHAsset encodeWithCoder:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x149ec7770'"

Answer (score 3):

One possible way is to turn the image into **data** and add that data to your *managedObject*.
Your attribute type for the attribute in the X should be set to "binary data".

Otherwise (e.g. if you want to interact with the original file from Photos or iCloud) you could save the **local identifier**, and then use

```
fetchAssetsWithLocalIdentifiers
```

to get the image again after receiving the *identifier* from your *managedObject*.

Hope that helps you!

Comment: How can I get PHAsset using  fetchAssetsWithLocalIdentifiers again?

Comment: Like https://developer.apple.com/documentation/photokit/phasset/1624732-fetchassets shows, the function fetchAssets() with the identifier as parameter, returns the PHAsset you re looking for.